# Barcoding in Ms Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, count, split, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to set up barcoding for inventory in access but i've hit a brick wall with formulas. I'm using a split form that pulls all the items at one facility (this is using a query), with the item details on top and a datasheet on the bottom. What I need to do when I scan the barcode (Barcode scan just sends a number and then hits enter):
Show the item in question, Check off the item (in the scanned field) then at the top have it count the number of items to scan compared to the total number of items.

this is my database

http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g74f12f7ca2e5574c999399633d9019b01b77824ed

This is the last step for me in this database, and I've never had ANY formal training so I'm really in a bind here. Thank you all so much.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This is a good question, but it is completely unclear what your precise problem is.  What is not working the way you want?  Can you make the result of the scan show in Access -- or is it undetectable?  Is there a part of the VBA code that is perhaps critical?  If so, post it.

Answer (score 0):

please refer to the software development guide of your scanner for better understanding. there's an SDK for motorola barcode scanners and POS for.net for any brand of scanner. If you tried POS for .net, they have a sample app where the simulated scanner sends the barcode info in a textbox(inside a form) which you can manipulate to save in a database.